# set custom shipping amount programmatically in Magento2

Tags: magento2.2, shipping, quote, magento2.2.6

I am trying to set the custom shipping amount to quote or order without shipping method. Main thing is that shipping amount have to be stored in the database.
Please help me for the same .. My shipping amount calculation is happening in checkout page.

Comment: did you got any solutions related it